# Can't use sort() with HttpClient subscribe, property 'sort' does not exist on type 'Object'

Tags: angular, typescript, sorting, http, httpclient

I'm moving from Http to HttpClient but I get some errors now that I can't use map() to sort the result.

With HttpClient I get Property 'sort' does not exist on type 'Object'.

```
this.getConcept().subscribe(res => {
    res.sort((f, n): number => {
        if (f.code < n.code) return -1;
        if (f.code > n.code) return 1;

        return 0;
    }); 
    console.error(res);
    this.arrConcept = res;
});
```

with Http I can sort it without problems

```
this.getConcept().map(this.extractData).subscribe(res => {
    res.sort((f, n): number => {
        if (f.code < n.code) return -1;
        if (f.code > n.code) return 1;

        return 0;
    }); 
    console.error(res);
    this.arrConcept = res;
});
```

Comment: You didn't post the code of getConcept(). It retrns an Observable<Object>, and should instead return an Observable<Array<Something>>. Read the documentation: https://angular.io/guide/http#type-checking-the-response

Comment: You can't sort an object, So make sure your method is returning an array

Comment: getConcept() is just this.http.get(this.url)

Comment: You have a different code in there. With Http you map the response using the function extractData that may or may not transform the data. In the HttpClient version you should
1) Use that function to extract the data and return that type
2) If it only maps (which is now done automatically by get()) the subscribe parameter should be of the same type the extractData function returns

Comment: what is the code for `this.extractData` ?

Comment: extractData(res: Response) { const body = res.json(); return body; }

Comment: That's the problem. As explained in the documentation, that I linked to, it should be `return this.http.get<Array<Something>>(this.url)`. Again, read the documentation. That's what it's for: you take 10 minutes to read it, learn plenty of things, and then spare hours

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by just specifying the type of `res` as `[]`

```
this.getConcept().subscribe((res:[]) => {
    res.sort((f, n): number => {
        if (f.code < n.code) return -1;
        if (f.code > n.code) return 1;

        return 0;
    }); 
    console.error(res);
    this.arrConcept = res;
});
```

The code then knows that res is an array and an array has a `sort` method.

If you have an interface defined for the array, it would be better to use it. For example:

```
(res:IConcept[]) => { ... }
```

Comment: When trying to implement this solution I get:  A tuple type element list cannot be empty.

Comment: You may want to create a stackblitz example so we can better help you.

Comment: Got it working like this (res: any[]) instead of (res:[])

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer by any mean. Using any[] is telling the typesystem to ignore basically anything you are typing, for that matter you may use any. Please read the comments on your question.

Answer (score 1):

.sort is a property of arrays or objects, you should type your return accordingly and the method will be then available. If you are unsure about the return of your method, give it a any[]. Something like:

```
this.getConcept().subscribe((res: any[]) => {
res.sort((f, n): number => {
    if (f.code < n.code) return -1;
    if (f.code > n.code) return 1;

    return 0;
}); 
console.error(res);
this.arrConcept = res;
});
```

But preferably you should rewrite your method to return an array of the appropriate type. Also, type the return of your function as well. In fact, if you want to use typescript, type everything - that is what typescript is for! =)

Answer (score 0):

**readonly**

I got this error trying to `.sort()` an readonly array. You can copy it by using the `.slice()` function with no parameters. On the copied array `.sort()` works fine.